# How to get count of pairs giving rise to correlation values using the cor() function

Tags: r

I like the `cor()` function but would like to know how to get a count of the number of pairs in a sparse matrix giving rise to the correlation values.
Many thanks.

Here's a very simplified version of the kind of data table I have.
[example data table picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MYGS.png)

I've also added a cut down version of the actual file I'm working on [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/odpwc6uhtbj912w/test_assay_matrix_for_correlation_counts.csv?dl=0)

What I'd like is to find a way to give me something like the following matrix (below is from the pic rather than the file in the hyperlink):
[example desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcaVz.png)

This shows how many pairs of values there are in common between columnA and columnB so I can see which columns are worth comparing in a correlation. Does that make sense?

> dput(mat)
>   structure(list(A = c(9.4, 9.4, 4.7, 1.2, NA, 0.6, 7.712, 0.2, 
>   NA, NA, 3.13, NA, 1.56, 6.25, NA, NA, 0.9471, NA, 1.56, 1.2, 
>   0.78, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), B = c(4.7, 12.5, 2.3, 2.3, 9.4, 
>   0.78, 9.45, 0.6, NA, NA, 3.13, NA, 2.3, 6.25, NA, NA, 10.72, 
>   NA, 2.3, 12.5, 6.25, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), C = c(4.7, 9.4, 
>   4.7, 0.6, NA, 0.6, 10.84, 0.2, 3.67, 2.345, 3.13, 3.288, 1.56, 
>   9.4, 11.21, 0.6, 2.256, 50, 1.56, 3.13, 0.78, 18.7, 0.66, 1.2, 
>   6.26, 6.258, 50)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
>   -27L))

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
outdf <- c()
for (x in colnames(mat)) {
  for (y in colnames(mat)) {
    subset <- mat[,c(x, y)]
    number_complete <- nrow(subset[complete.cases(subset),])
    row <- c(x, y, number_complete)
    outdf <- rbind(outdf, row)
  }
}
outdf <- data.frame(outdf)
dcast(outdf, X1 ~ X2)
# X1  A  B  C
# 1  A 14 14 14
# 2  B 14 15 14
# 3  C 14 14 26
```

Comment: That looks awesome Aidan, I understand some of it, but can't get it to work on my example (maybe presence of NA is a problem?) - sorry I didn't post a link to my actual data until now. I'm doing mat <- my_data_frame & then trying to execute your code. I should add that I'm using RStudio, but I assume that shouldn't make a difference

Comment: Japp mentions a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610) ... this means we can actually run the code you are having a problem with. Please provide that.

Comment: I don't have any code, just the data - I've now edited the problem with a link to the data file I'm using. Many thanks

Comment: Please use dput(your_dataframe) so that we know exactly what data you are working with (and the type). (For example you must have code that reads in the csv, and converts it to a sparse matrix ... we need that code, or the end result).

Comment: Aidan, that's perfect. Very many thanks for all your help & apologies for my beginner errors on here.

Comment: No problem. If it was helpful, you can "accept" this answer by clicking the check mark next to it.